# What position-sizing methods are used in futures trading?

Tags: risk-management, portfolio-management, position-sizing

Beyond optimal / partial f and a few other older methods, there's very little information out there for futures trading.

Comment: Hi dvegadvol, and welcome to the site. It would help if you give some reasons for why you are asking the question. Why exactly are you not happy with the optimal/fractional Kelly criterion?

Answer (score 7):

The [Kelly criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) is a very popular bet-sizing method.  [Edward Thorp](http://www.edwardothorp.com/) has written a great deal on this topic.  You can try googling for more, or start with his [review of the concept](http://www.edwardothorp.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/KellyCriterion2007.pdf), or a recent paper, [Medium Term Simulations of The Full Kelly and Fractional Kelly Investment Strategies](http://www.edwardothorp.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/KellySimulationsNew.pdf).  This is not specific to futures, but I'm not sure why you would need something specific to futures.  I've never heard of optimal f, but at first blush it sounds a lot like a dumbed-down Kelly criterion.

Comment: Edward Thorp's review URL has changed, however, it is still available on the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20090206035006/http://www.edwardothorp.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/KellyCriterion2007.pdf .

Answer (score 4):

*Money Management Strategies for Futures Traders* by Nauzer J. Balsara is a good resource.

Answer (score 4):

Van Tharp's [Definitive Guide to Position Sizing](http://www.vantharp.com/products/definitive-guide-position-sizing.asp) identifies 31 separate position sizing models (be sure to check out the extended table of contents). Specifically for futures trading, I quite like Ryan Jones' Fixed Ratio position sizing, a nice overview of which is available [here](http://www.breakoutfutures.com/Newsletters/Newsletter0703.htm), book on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471316989) and OTT website [here](http://www.fixedratio.com/).